# View all foursquare venue photos online?

Tags: photo-sharing, foursquare

I've noticed Foursquare has recently started allowing users to upload photos with their check-ins. Is there a way of viewing all the photos uploaded for a venue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the Foursquare FAQ](http://support.foursquare.com/entries/368296-what-is-the-difference-between-a-check-in-photo-and-a-venue-photo) you can only view uploaded (check-in) photos if you are friends with the person checking in or they post them to Twitter & Facebook (and you are friends/follow them).  Photos added via check-ins are available through the persons activity, history and checkin detail pages.

Venue Photos are public and can be viewed by anyone on the Venue page.

> **What is the difference between a check-in photo and a venue photo?**
>
> If you add a photo to your check-in,
>   only your foursquare friends can view
>   it (or anyone who can see your posts
>   on Twitter/Facebook if you've posted
>   it there!). If you add a photo from
>   the venue view, it's a public venue
>   photo that any foursquare user can
>   see.

Comment: aah i see! cheers Barry!